# Serialising string arrays into json

Tags: json, serialization, go

So, I've been tinkering with go and have a small problem. I have something that needs to be serialised into a json like so.

```
{
  "name" : "Steel", 
  "things" : ["Iron", "Carbon"]
}
```

The struct to hold this looks like this.

```
type Message struct {
    name string
    things []string

}
```

and my code itself like this

```
func main() {
    i := Message{"Steel", []string{"Iron", "Carbon"}}
    fmt.Println(i);

    b, _ := json.Marshal(i)
    fmt.Printf(" Json %v\n", b);

    var o Message;
    json.Unmarshal(b, &o)
    fmt.Printf(" Decoded %v\n", o);
}
```

When I deserialise the data though, I get back an empty `Message` like so

```
{Steel [Iron Carbon]}
 Json [123 125]
 Decoded { []}
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export fields of the struct. Unexported fields are not included by `encoding/json`

```
type Message struct {
    Name string
    Things []string
}
```

The field names should begin with capital letters (Exported).

Comment: "Exported" would be the Go terminology here.

Comment: Thank you Aruna. I knew I was going to trip over the capital letters thing. 'twas just a matter of time.

Comment: If you want to have your JSON representation have different key names, you can annotate it in the struct, like `Name string \`json:"name"\``.